# A possible cause of Bus Error: Nonexistent physical address

Tags: crash, bus-error, sigbus

This is not a question, but rather an answer for a question I couldn't find here before.

I had an application that kept crashing with the message 'Bus error'. This happened non-deterministically in different parts of my code, usually after a long running time. The only hint was the associated si_code, was 'BUS_ADRERR: Nonexistent physical address'.

The reason for the crash is that I would re-compile the code, thus messing up the memory mapping for the executable file.

Answer (score 1):

I was running two Rscripts with different parameters simultaneously. The script at one point writes to and then subsequently reads from a file. I believe I got this error code from both scripts trying to write and read from the same file simultaneously.